# How to save state lxc container

Tags: lxc

I am using a virtual machine running Ubuntu. Here I have started a virtual host using `lxc-container`.

I assigned one IP address to this host. When I then shut down the VM, how do I return to that state after starting that lxc container again? I mean, so I don't have to assign an IP address again.

Comment: How did you set up your container? What network is it connected to (lxcbr0? br0?)

Comment: I solved by saving befire shutting down :)

Comment: If you could, please add that as an answer, and mark this as resolved. Also, your question description seems to be more related to 'assigning an IP' to a container, not saving the container state. If you agree, could you update the title of your question to help out others in the future? As it is, the description is misleading